# Trouble importing Beautiful Soup 4 in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, beautifulsoup

It looks like:

```
from BeautifulSoup.bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

and file structure is /BeautifulSoup/bs4/(everything in this folder)

The "builder" and "dammit" files seem to import fine, but I keep getting an error message for element.py:

ImportError: No module named bs4.element

Could anyone shed some light upon this? Thanks!

UPDATE:
Got rid of the BeautifulSoup outer folder and then `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` worked fine. Thanks for all the feedback :)

Comment: is /Beautiful in your system path?

Comment: For app engine, libraries need to be in your local project path.

Comment: @dragonx Yes beautifulsoup is in a folder in my local project path.